# scadalts-ui dependency @min-gb/vuejs-components is not in this registry

Tags: scadalts

Is there someone who can help me?
Thanks.

run `npm install`

GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@min-gb%2fvuejs-components - Not found

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@min-gb%2fvuejs-components - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@min-gb/vuejs-components@0.0.7' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Comment: Please post your question on the project's github (https://github.com/SCADA-LTS/Scada-LTS), it may be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

How NPM works: you download a source code without libraries, only a `package.json` file to describe libraries. So NPM install all dependencies into `node_modules` directory. This is the best method because you don't need to carry extra files into source code.

Unfortunately, `min-gb` does not exist on NPM repository. So ScadaLTS comes with min-gb in `node_modules` directory already. It comes already installed.

Check `min-gb` directory here
https://github.com/SCADA-LTS/Scada-LTS/tree/10b3c97506e79c3a3dc761fdf9e74df3d363d7cf/scadalts-ui/node_modules/%40min-gb/vuejs-components

Comment: "*So its comes in node_modules in source code.*" can you clarify what this means? What is the workaround to install the package?